Workbook.Open, getting dreaded Microsoft excel is waiting for another application to complete
VBA:
dim xl As New Excel.Application
dim wbkDATABASE  as Workbook
Set wbkDATABASE = xl.Workbooks.Open(strDATABASEfile)

The strDATABASEfile is stored on a teams / sharepoint folder, I am 99% certain this is network issue as the error happens sporadically.
I cannot seem to find a method to trap the error to avoid the pop up message box. As I am automating this on virtual desktop running every 60 minutes no one is there to see this error.
Anyone had luck solving this
I have reviewed Workbook.open to try and find a parameter to control or trap this with no luck
